# Converting a Matrix with Variables to Numerical Form in RPL Programming Language

Tags: variables, generics, math, matrix, rpl

I'm having trouble converting my matrix with variables to a form with only numbers, and I don't know how to do it.

Here is the matrix: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4YzR.png

I think I have to type the NUM command somewhere, but I don't know where to put it.

To summarize, I just want to find the numerical form of the matrix, so that when I pass it to my HP50g, my variable 'M' is already in its numerical form.